# iframe allow vertical scrollbar but not horizontal

Tags: html

I have an HTML iframe.  I want it to be scrollable vertically, but not horizontally.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automatically shows vertical scrollbar if content is longer than viewable area:

```
.iframe-class { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; }
```

Forces vertical scrollbar even if content is not longer than viewable area:

```
.iframe-class { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; }
```